# Create a single object from chained comparison in Python

Tags: python, highs

I am toying around with chained comparison in Python, that is, something like `a < b < c`. According to the docs, it is evaluated as `(a < b) and (b < c)`, where `b` is evaluated only once.

I do this to save inequalities of symbolic expressions to a list. For example:

```
l = Keeper()
a = Symbol()
b = Symbol()
c = Symbol()
l.add(a < b)
l.add(b < c)
```

This works nicely. Now I've seen in the HiGHS documentation something and am baffled how they do it. [Here](https://ergo-code.github.io/HiGHS/dev/interfaces/python/example-py/) they give this example:

```
x0 = h.addVar(lb = 0, ub = 4)
x1 = h.addVar(lb = 1, ub = 7)

h.addConstr(5 <= x0 + 2*x1 <= 15)
```

with the implication that this means what one would expect with standard mathematic notation.

How do they do it?  The best I can do is create either  the `5 <= x0 + 2*x1` part or the `x0 + 2*x1 <= 15`, but never both.

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe, as you suggest that a<b<c is unfolded as (a<b)and(b<c), you should overload the and for your Symbol class?

Comment: @Sasha `and` can't be overloaded in Python

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but I checked:

```
class C():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __and__(self, y):
        return C('(' + self.value + '&' + y.value + ')')

    def __lt__(self, y):
        return C('(' + self.value + '<' + y.value + ')')

    def __bool__(self):
        return self

a = C('1')
b = C('2')
c = C('3')
print((a < b < c).value)
```

and get:

```
TypeError: __bool__ should return bool, returned C
```

so maybe the library you mention somehow overrides this prohibition of __bool__ returning a bool?

Comment: But that only turns the rich return value into a bool. It still does combine the two parts of the comparison.

Comment: @cxxl Yes, I said it is not an answer, it throws an error; would the compiler have allowed the code as I have written it, overlooking the return value, this would have been an answer, I believe...